# How to populate collection dropdown with hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Goal: Populate dropdown with hash from controller. Has three options for user to choose. I have tried and result in a few different errors: No name method error, argument error, and mapping nil error. Right now dropdown is just showing attributes of form, not what I want. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Rails v 4.2.4

Controller: registrations_controller.rb

```
@survey_collection = [1 => "Text 1", 2 => "Text 2", 3 => "Text 3"]
```

View: edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.select :survey, collection: @survey_collection, prompt: 'Select', required: false %>
```

note: If I change to f.collection_select I get argument error.

Devise update account params: application_controller.rb

```
:survey
```

I also tried `:survey => []`

Added survey column to Users table

```
class AddSurveyToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :survey, :integer
  end
end
```

In User model if I put `has_many :survey` I get NameError in Users::Registrations#edit with uninitialized constant User::Survey

Update: should be `has_many :surveys` plural I think but still not working overall.

**Answer:**
Needed to use array of arrays instead of hash and put that in my def edit. I had it in my def update in registrations_controller.

```
def edit
    @survey_collection = [['Text 1', 1], ['Text 2', 2], ['Text 3', 3]]
    render :edit
  end
```

Also, form dropdown should be this:

```
<%= f.select(:survey, @survey_collection, :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

Comment: you need to use array of arrays instead of hash to generate correct select input. in order to that you can do it like this: `@survey_collection = [[1, 'Text 1'], [2, 'Text 2'], [3, 'Text 3']]`

Comment: I also tried that and same result where the controller is not talking to the view for some reason-not populating the collection. It's not picking up the hash. It should because it is in the def update that is called in the form.

Comment: Everything else in users profile form is connecting so it must be issue with the dropdown. Not sure.

Comment: can you try to populate select input with this format? `<%= f.select(:survey, @survey_collection, :prompt => 'Select') %>`

Comment: in which method do you define `@survey_collection` in the controller?

Comment: you should define `@survey_collection` in edit action to pass it to form. update action called after form submitted.

Comment: ok, I will try. This is all that shows for that method in controller  def edit
    render :edit
  end

Comment: That did something. Error is gone and now showing 1, 2, 3 as dropdown options, but not the text in the array of arrays. Thank you for the help, getting closer.

Comment: swap the values in the arrays in `@survey_collection` that will solve that problem

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. I just need to work on saving it to db. Much appreciated. Will update my answer so no confusion to others.

Comment: Please don't put your answer in your question, post your answer as an answer and accept it as the solution.